# How can I insert Model data into jQuery in a View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have jQuery similar to this on a view:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#yourID").makeAsyncUploader({
            upload_url: "/Images/AsyncUpload",
            flash_url: '/Scripts/swfupload.swf',
            button_image_url: '/Scripts/blankButton.png'
        });
    });        
</script>
```

I need to change the upload_url to receive a parameter so that it goes to a Url like:

```
/Images/AsyncUpload/23
```

... where 23 is the value of Model.ProjectId.

Is there a way to inject the value I need into the jQuery?  I tried ...

```
upload_url: "/Images/AsyncUpload/<%= Model.ProjectId %>",
```

... but intellisense was having none of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it? Intellisense certainly does hate ASP code blocks inside Javascript, but for me at least, the line you tried would work. The `<%= %>` tags get rendered before being sent to the client.

Comment: You're right. This does work as-is.  I never checked it because intellisense lied to me.

Comment: Intellisense can be a cruel mistress.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the magic is in the single quotes.  Note that I like to split it and do string concatenation so that the value stands on its own.

```
 upload_url: "/Images/AsyncUpload/" + '<%= Model.ProjectId %>',
```